# Multiple types on a Java multi-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

From what I know, only one type of object/literal can be stored on a multi-dimensional Java array.

so for instance, on a 2-dim'l array a[][], I can not store
 a Type-1 array on a[0] and Type-2 array on a[1] unless there's some polymorphic relationship between Type-1 & Type-2 and I put it into use there.

I'm looking to verify that there's no way to get around this. so, I cannot somehow put an int array on a[0], a char array on a[1]-- Java arrays are single-type.

I'm aware that I can declare 2 parallel arrays-- one int[] and one char[] and that solves it.

Thanks in advance.

//=====================

Edit: The good old object class solves it-- as the useful answers below pointed out. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Why are collections not fitting? You could use a something like List<Object, List<Object>>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an `array` of Objects:

```
Object[] x = new Object[2];
x[0] = new Integer[3];
x[1] = new String[3];
```

Comment: @Roam P.S. my answer was the first.

Comment: Yes first, but it did not show the usage of different types, which you added later.

Comment: well- can ttell by the secs. one of oyu got the upvote, the other the accept. trying to be fair to e1.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Object[]`.

```
Object[] arrays = new Object[2];
arrays[0] = new int[10];
arrays[1] = new char[10];
```